# How can I make Octopus execute ps1 scripts in the content folder in a NuGet package?

Tags: powershell, nuget, octopus-deploy

When I use the `nuget pack` functionality in Azure DevOps, it creates a NuGet package with all the project files in the `content` folder. This includes some scripts like `PostDeploy.ps1`.

When Octopus Deploy tries to release this, it says it won't execute the `ps1` scripts because they're in a subfolder, instead of the root folder ( = next to the content folder).

Now, Octopus encourages using NuGet packages, and these `ps1` scripts are in the *root of the project*. So I would assume that there's an obvious solution that I'm not seeing here.

**How can I make Octopus run these Pre-/Post-Deploy scripts?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ultimately solved this by not using NuGet itself for this at all.

Instead we used [the OctoPack NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/OctoPack/).
This package creates Octopus-compliant NuGet packages via msbuild.